# How to make Multilevel Accordian with checkbox by using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I wanted to make something like this:

[image]

But so far, I could only make two level accordion and I do not exactly know and sure how to code this further so that it has 3, 4 or even 5 level with ability to check/uncheck the checkboxes.

These are more or less of what I got so far:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="accordion">      
  <li>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /><a href="#">EU --- Europa</a></div>
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li>
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox"><a href="#">EU-DE --- Germany</a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox"><a href="#">EU-ES --- Espana</a></div>
        <ul class="accordion">
          <div><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox"><a href="#">EU-ES-AN --- Andalusia</a></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox"><a href="#">EU-ES-AR --- Aragon</a></div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /><a href="#">NA --- North America</a></div>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /><a href="#">LA --- America Latina</a></div>
  </li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 170px;
}
.accordion div {
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5 5 5 7px;
    list-style: circle;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.accordion ul{
    display: none;
}
.accordion ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
.accordion a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
.accordion a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){


  $(".accordion > li > div").click(function(){
    $(".accordion > li").toggleClass("display")
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('.accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
  });


  //clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
  $(".parentCheckBox").on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('ul').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  }); 

});
```

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: Your script is only acting on the top level checkboxes with `id="parentCheckBox"` All checkboxes should have the same class name and then use `$(".checkBox").on(...`

Comment: And you will probably want other logic in your script - e.g. if a checkbox is checked and all its sibling checkboxes are also checked, then check its parent etc.

Comment: You can use following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/93s498j9/) as reference.